# Update all the key values of a dynamic object in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a object which has dynamic keys all the values in that are numeric integers, i like to update all the key values in that object

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6395fc7b1c5a0c4a5fc9bd8e"),
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("638da89d0066308efe081709"),
        ObjectId("63844feadf507942caaf90e3"),
        ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
    ],
    "type" : "GROUP",
    "unReadCount" : {
        "638da89d0066308efe081709" : 0,
        "63844feadf507942caaf90e3" : 0,
        "638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f" : 0
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-12-11T21:21:23.815+05:30"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-12-11T22:48:33.953+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0
},
```

I want to increment the **unReadCount** entire object values, please note the **unReadCount** object keys are not static it varies document to document. I tried with normal $inc operator it thrown error stating that `has the field 'unReadCount' of non-numeric type object"` **$** wouldn't work as its not an array.

Please note that am trying to achieve this in MongoDB, i can do this via JS code by fetching the records and looping through it, but i like to do it in MongoDB/Mongoose. Any clue/help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you need

```
db.tests.updateMany({},[
{
    $addFields: {
        unReadCountArray: { $objectToArray: "$unReadCount" }
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        unReadCountArray: {
            $map: {
                input: "$unReadCountArray",
                as: "unReadCount",
                in: 
                {
                    $mergeObjects: [ { k:"$$unReadCount.k", v: {$add: ["$$unReadCount.v", 1] }}, null ] 
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        unReadCount: {
            $arrayToObject: '$unReadCountArray'
        }
    }
},{
    $unset:'unReadCountArray'
},
 { $set: { modified: "$$NOW"}  }])
```